# For loop taking a long time

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

I am simulating an Irwin Hall distribution of 1,000,000 replicates, each replicate is a sum of 100 uniform random variables. I created this program and I think its right but MATLAB has been running all night and not finished, so something (obviously) wrong but I can't see where. Here is my program, I hope someone might see the issue.

```
n=100; % Nb of samples
N=1000000; %Nb of replicates

for jj=1:N
    for ii=1:n
        x(ii)=rand();
    end
    s(jj)=sum(x);
    mu=mean(s);
    sigma2=var(s);
    sigma=std(s);
    S(jj)=1-normcdf((70-mu)/sigma);
    if mod(jj, 100000)==0
        jj
    end
end

histogram(S)
```

Comment: Is the space in your division `/s igma` really there? Also, why not just `x = rand(100,1);`

Comment: 1 million iterations will obv require a lot of time!! Also consider [pre-allocating](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) the memory for `x`, `s` , `S` to save up some time!

Comment: the /s igma has been corrected but the issue remain :(

Comment: @Orongo why'd you copy my code to the question itself, but left a comment on Dohyun's answer? Don't copy my code please, instead, explain in comments **on my answer** (since that's where you got this code from) what is unclear. I'll roll back the edit you made, as both my and Dohyun's answer make no sense anymore with the current question.

Answer (score 5):

```
n=1e2; % Nb of samples
N=1e6; % Nb of replicates
s = zeros(1,N); % INITIALISE, INITIALISE, INITIALISE
S = zeros(1,N); % INITIALISE, INITIALISE, INITIALISE

for jj=1:N
    x=rand(n,1); % Remove redundant inner loop
    s(1,jj)=sum(x);
    tmp = s(1,1:jj); % Create temporary storage for convenience
    mu=mean(tmp);
    sigma=std(sigma2); % You don't need the variance at all
    S(1,jj)=1-normcdf((70-mu)/sigma);
     if mod(jj, 1e5)==0
         disp('We are at iteration %i',jj); % Proper display command
     end
end

histogram(S)
```

This code ran in half a second using `N=1e4` on my i5-750 processor.

The most important things are: don't print to a console like your `jj`. Either don't print at all, or use a `disp` command for clarity. Printing to a console takes a lot of time. Also [initialise your variables](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). Growing variables in a loop takes very long. Each time you increase the length of the variable, a million times here, you force MATLAB to first create a variable with the initial length+1, then copy the contents, then delete the old variable. That's probably what is taking your code so long.

I also used a temporary variable `tmp` to make the conversion in your code slightly easier.

Comment: Nice speed! That disp looks fishy though. -- Out of principle I would calculate the std based on the var (rather than based on the data again).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I was rather surprised by there being the sole `jj` in the original code. I suspect he wants to have some kind of progress meter, so that's what I got there for him with a proper call to `disp`.

Comment: I understand why you put this in place, but this call does not seem to work.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin hehe, yea, I forgot to escape the single quote. Left out the shortening of *are*  and fixed it that way. Good catch

Answer (score 2):

I preallocated variable `S` and vectorized some of the code.

```
tic;

n=100; % Nb of samples
N=1000000; %Nb of replicates

x = rand(n,N); % x(ii) = rand();
s = sum(x); % s = sum(x);
mu = cumsum(s)./(1:N); % mu = mean(s);

S = zeros(N,1);
for jj=1:N
    sigma=std(s(1:jj));
    S(jj)=1-normcdf((70-mu(jj))/sigma);
    if ~mod(jj,100000)
        fprintf('%d %.2f\n',jj,toc);
    end
end

toc

histogram(S)
```

I get

```
N        orginal  modified
----------------------------
1e+05     54.07      31.9
2e+05    246.37     173.6
3e+05    621.06    450.91
4e+05    1161.2    835.03
5e+05    1837.5    1329.4
6e+05    2661.4    1930.3
```

with an i5-6200U processor and 8GB DDR3 RAM.

since the computation gets heavier as `jj` gets bigger, it will takes quite some time if you run the code for `N = 10^6`.

Since you did not preallocate variables, the difference will be greater as you set `N` bigger.

Even though MATLAB can handle modification of variable size, MATLAB *highly* recommends you to preallocate the memory. Every time MATLAB hits the boundary of your variable, MATLAB tries to reallocate the memory and it takes much more time. Even if you cannot compute exact memory size, it is better to preallocate some variables with a rough guess and then erase the unused part after the loop.

Comment: That is really good to know and will come in handy. The run took 6 hours and the results and code is now in the question line.  I feel a bit struck of the results, as this is a learning exercise I am surprised by the result and run time as they both extra ordinary.